# How can I log an access token in spring-security-oauth2-client:5.5.0 lib?

Tags: spring-security

I want to log the body of response of access token request and then mask it.
Smth like this

```
{"access_token": "F******", "expires_in": 3600, "token_type": "Bearer"}
```

How can I do it?
I have found where the token is received, but don't understand how to log it.

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient#getTokenResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient` has no observability built into it. Also, it deserializes the JSON response directly into the `OAuth2AccessTokenResponse` object, so there is no intermediate string representation that could be logged anyway. In order to log the response from the access token endpoint, you would need to make the request to that endpoint yourself with either `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`.

One alternative is to tune up the logging on your HTTP client library so that it will output the Bearer token when it is sent along with your request. It will *not* be masked, however.

Another alternative is to add a simple exchange function like the following to your `WebClient.Builder`. This will allow you to log the outbound request having the assigned bearer token and will still allow you to mask sensitive values appropriately.

```java
webClientBuilder.exchangeFunction(request -> {
    val exchangeFunction = ExchangeFunctions.create(new ReactorClientHttpConnector());
    builder.exchangeFunction(request -> {
        var headers = request.headers().entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "=" + (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Authorization") ? "***" : entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        if (!headers.isEmpty()) headers = ", " + headers;
        var message = String.format("<%1$s %2$s%3$s>%n", request.method(), request.url(), headers);
        log.info(message);
        return exchangeFunction.exchange(request);
});
```